# Date diff in Teradata

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I'm trying to do date difference between two `dim_ck` fields. If it's `< 30`, then I need to set a flag `Y`, else `N`.

Steps followed:

As it's a `dim_ck`, I converted it to `Date` from `dim_ck`.
There is one value with `-3`, so it didn't allow me to convert, so I tried to set a default date to `-3` and then was able to convert it to `Date`. The below query returns `Y` and `N` result in Terdata DB, but it's not taking the date difference correctly.

For ex:  `1998/07/31 - 2015/10/01 = Y`, it's actually `> 30`, so it should return `N`. Please help.

Query:

```
SELECT date_dim_ck, 
   end_date_dim_ck, 
   CASE 
     WHEN( CASE 
       WHEN date_dim_ck = -3 THEN (To_date('01/01/1753', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) 
          ELSE Cast(( date_dim_ck - 19000000 ) AS DATE) 
     END - ( Cast (( end_date_dim_ck - 19000000 ) AS DATE) ) ) < 30 
     THEN 'Y' 
       ELSE 'N' 
     END AS FLAG 
   FROM table
```

Comment: What are the actual values of date_dim_ck that are greater than zero?

Answer (score 2):

#1: You didn't convert SQL Server's `DATEDIFF (day, date_dim_ck, end_date_dim_ck)` correctly.

`SELECT DATE '1998-07-31' - DATE '2015-10-01'` returns `-6217` which is way less than 30 :-)

#2: There's no need for applying `TO_DATE` plus a format, Teradata supports Standard SQL date literals, `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

```
CASE 
  WHEN Cast (( end_date_dim_ck - 19000000 ) AS DATE)  -   
    CASE 
      WHEN date_dim_ck = -3
        THEN DATE '1753-01-01'
        ELSE Cast(( date_dim_ck - 19000000 ) AS DATE) 
    END < 30 
  THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N' 
END AS FLAG
```

Assuming that 1753-01-01 actually doesn't exist within the data:

```
CASE 
  WHEN Cast ((end_date_dim_ck - 19000000 ) AS DATE)
     - Cast((NullIf(date_dim_ck,-3) - 19000000 ) AS DATE) < 30 
  THEN 'Y' 
  ELSE 'N' 
END AS FLAG
```

Btw, the lowest date Teradat supports is `DATE '0001-01-01'`.

Comment: Thank you very much dnoeth. It works. when add it in the SSIS package, I'm getting this error: [Teradata Source [260]] Error: TPT Export error encountered during Initiate phase. TPTAPI_INFRA: API306: Error: Conflicting data length for column(4) - FLAG. Source column's data length is (2) Target column's data length is (3).                In SQL server, created the FLAG column with data type CHAR(1), NOT NULL DEFUALT 0. Please advice.

Comment: @K.Dharma:  Any literal string always has a Unicode character set, of course Y/N can easily be stored in Latin. The data length error is due to some problem regarding defined/expected byte length, a single Unicode character is up to 3 bytes (UTF8) or 2 bytes (UTF16), seems to be different for source & target.

Comment: Thank you dnoeth.  I tried this, getting syntax error like, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier between the AS keyword and the CHAR keyword.                                                             QUERY:  CAST(CASE 
  WHEN Cast ((END_DATE_DIM_CK - 19000000 ) AS DATE)
     - Cast((NullIf(DATE_DIM_CK,-3) - 19000000 ) AS DATE) < 30 
  THEN 'Y' 
  ELSE 'N' 
END AS CHAR(1) ) AS FLAG

Comment: @K.Dharma: This is valid syntax, must be something else

Comment: Hi, how to add this"TRANSLATE('0' USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN) AS VARCHAR(6)" in the below query?                                                QUERY: CAST(CASE WHEN Cast ((END_DATE_DIM_CK - 19000000 ) AS DATE) - Cast((NullIf(DATE_DIM_CK,-3) - 19000000 ) AS DATE) < 30 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS VARCHAR(6) ) AS FLAG                                                                                                            Thank you!

Comment: @K.Dharma: I don't know, what you want. You wrote it's `CHAR(1) DEFAULT '0'`, but your CASE returns `'Y'` & `'N'`. And you want a `VARCHAR(6)`, crazy.

Comment: I'm getting length issue in SSIS package, trying different options, i can use CHAR(1) with the UNICODE_TO_LATIN conversion but don't know how to add it in the above query, tried but was getting syntax error.

Comment: @K.Dharma: Add it around the current CASE: `TRANLSATE(CAST(CASE ... AS CHAR(1)) USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN)`

Comment: Getting syntax error:                                                                                                   CAST(tranlsate(cast( 
CASE 
WHEN cast ((eff_date_dim_ck - 19000000 ) AS date) - cast((NULLIF(date_dim_ck,-3) - 19000000 ) AS date) < 30 THEN 
  'Y' 
  ELSE 'N' 
END 
AS char(1)) using unicode_to_latin)) AS flag

Comment: @K.Dharma: It's `translate`, not `tranlsate`:)